# Strange vim registers behavior when used with execute "normal

Tags: vim

Why does the following command does not use the content of what is first registered in the unnamed register, if this content is a number ?

```
execute "normal! cc".(@"+1)."\<esc>"
```

Comment: Your command works form me when I have a number in the unamed register. As an alternative you can do `:execute "normal! cc\<c-r>"\<esc>\<c-a>"`

Comment: Isn't cc meant to store the content of the current line in the unnamed register ?

Comment: Absolutely correct so that mapping wouldn't work. Probably better to use the `"0` register instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string concatenation is done in fact before execution, which seems logical. The following code has the behaviour I expected.

```
normal! cc
execute "normal! ".(@"+1)."\<esc>"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, as long as the default register contains *only* a number. Leading whitespace will cause the string to be evaluated as `0`.

```
:echo "1" + 1
2
:echo " 1" + 1
1
```

You can avoid that by explicitly converting the string to a number:

```
:echo str2nr(" 1") + 1
2
```

---

Note: If you don't care about the `'autoindent'` behavior of `cc`, you could also use the lower-level `setline()`:

```
:call setline('.', str2nr(@") + 1)
```

Comment: Please try the command in question after saving with yy a line containing a number followed by a carriage return. Then test it on a line containing a different number followed by a carriage return. It gives me the first saved number incremented.

Comment: Yes, what do you expect? That it increments the current line's number?